# What is the difference between "congestión del tráfico" and "congestión de tráfico"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

What is the difference between these?

1. congestión **del** tráfico.
2. congestión **de** tráfico.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The title of the question should be more descriptive: what is "them"?

Comment: I have edited the title for you, I hope you have learned for your next question :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is which one is the object of the sentences, in the first one you say:

> "La congestión del tráfico", where "traffic" is the object and it is "congested"

On the second one:

> "La congestión de tráfico", where "the congested traffic" is the object like in the answer of @MikO: 
>   "Las congestiones de tráfico son un gran problema" but I also believe they can be used indistinctly.

Note: "Traffic jam" is more popular and less formal. If you meant this usage, a more adequate form in Spanish is "Embotellamiento"

Comment: Both "embotellamiento" and "atasco" are used frequently in Spain. "Retención" (`Hay retenciones en las entradas a Madrid`) is also used, but it is more formal. "Congestión de tráfico" is less common.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any difference and I think both sentences are interchangeable.

If you want a slight difference, I'd say that the option 1 could be a bit more concrete than option 2, for example:

> Hay una gran congestión **del** tráfico en la autopista A1 en estos
>   momentos.

o

> Las congestones **de** tráfico son un gran problema para los que
>   trabajan en las grandes ciudades.

But as I said, this difference is a bit forced and I think both sentences are used indistinctly...

*Note: I'd personally go for the option 1.*